# How to Navigate to Different screen from Header in React Native (as I am Using props)?

Tags: react-native, react-props

Below is a code of home.js, navigator.js, cart.js, app.js file.
I want to include my clickable image in header in home page in such a way that when I click that Image I can navigate to Cart screen.
I have tried all the ways and searched google to but cant find solution to my problem

//code in Home.js

```
    import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Button,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
const Home = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      hello world
    </View>
  );
};

Home.navigationOptions = {
  headerTitle: "Home Page",
  headerTintColor: "#27A127",
  headerTitleStyle: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontStyle: "italic",
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  headerRight: () => (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          props.navigation.navigate("CartScreen");>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 45, height: 45, margin: 20 }}
          source={require("../assets/cart.png")}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 45, height: 45, margin: 20 }}
          source={require("../assets/search.png")}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  ),
};
```

//Code in Navigator.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Cart from "../screens/Cart";

import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: Home,
  CartScreen: Cart,
});
export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

//code in cart.js, I want to go on this screen

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Cart = () => {
  return <View>Cart screen</View>;
};
export default Cart;

//code in App.js
import React from "react";
import Navigator from "./navigation//Navigator";

const App = () => {
  return <Navigator />;
};

export default App;
```

// code in App.js

```
 import React from "react";
    import Navigator from "./navigation//Navigator";
    
    const App = () => {
      return <Navigator />;
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Your path looks weird to me `import Navigator from "./navigation//Navigator";`

Comment: nope I fixed that